# Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' cannot be used for constructor parameter of type 'System.Int32'\r\nParameter name: arguments[0]

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

I was doing the code below and EFCore throws

> Expression of type `System.Nullable'1[System.Int32]` cannot be used for constructor parameter of type `System.Int32'\r\nParameter name: arguments[0]`

```
var data= await _dbContext.Set<Person>().Select(person =>person.Profile != null ? 
new ProfileDto(org.Profile.Id , org.Profile.Nickname) : null).ToListAsync();
```

A Person either have a profile or none, so Profile property on Person is optional.

Comment: `ProfileDto` constructor expects and `int` value as first parameter, but it looks like `org.Profile.Id` is of type `int?` (nullable int). that's why you are seeing this error. You might want to do `ProfileDto(org.Profile.Id.GetValueOrDefaiult()) , org.Profile.Nickname)`

Comment: Make types in ProfileDto's contructor nullable and just get their actual values via .Value

Answer (score 1):

Another work around is to create a static method on ProfileDto, for example,

```
public class ProfileDto
{
  public static ProfileDto CreateFromDb(int id, string nickname)
  {
    // this is a constuctor.
     return new ProfileDto(id,nickname);
  }
}
```

//Then do:

```
{
var data= await _dbContext.Set<Person>().Select(person =>person.Profile != null ? 
ProfileDto.CreateFromDb(org.Profile.Id , org.Profile.Nickname) : null).ToListAsync();
}
```